Creating a Particle System based off a Probability Distribution Function
I am working on a project that involves setting up a particle system whose density is dependent on the density from the origin. The project involves using a probability distribution function (PDF) to create a particle cloud that is meant to recreate the electron clouds of a Hydrogen atom.
I have tried using a python script implementing the monte-carlo method, but i am unable to control particle positions individually
The distribution function is $\frac{{1}}{{8} a^{{3}}} \left( {2} - \frac{r}{a}\right)^{{2}}
e^{\frac{-r}{a}} r^{{2}}$, where r is the distance from the center and 'a' is the bohr radius = 0.0529
This particular PDF has a shape similar to a dumbbell (A 2p orbital along any axis)
My current ideas include using a curve guide to influence the particle system but that does not seem to work. Geometry nodes might work as well. Another possibility is using a python script [further help needed :) ]
Attempts:
Monte Carlo Attempt:

Particle System Attempts:

Thanks for the help :)
The final result should look something like this:
https://asliceofcuriosity.fr/assets/atom/orbitalsApp-1M.html
Useful references:
https://youtu.be/W2Xb2GFK2yc?si=KlLutH23ZIqHasEJ
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qVwYh9pZjLs
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8DL4ruQSObc

for sure i wouldn't use particles system for that, but Geometry nodes. Also i recommend posting/showing what you tried so far e.g. a blend file. As you write it that way, it could be read as "i am searching for someone doing my work".

ah sorry i didnt mean it like that. however i cant seem to find the option to upload the file
